# Inner join with Count in SQL and group by

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have this table called Equipos.

```
id  idType
1   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   4
```

And this other table which I want to Inner Join with (the catalogue with descriptions or ids).

```
id  descripcion
1   Macbook
2   iMac
3   Dell Lap
4   Dell Lap OP
```

I want something like

```
descripcion   count
Macbook       1
iMac          1
Dell Lap      1
Dell Lap OP   2
```

This is what Im trying so far.

```
select tipoId, count(tipoId) 
from Equipos eq 
group by tipoId 
inner join TipoEquipo tip on tip.id=eq.idType
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Learn some SQL syntax.  I doubt your query will run.

Comment: group by comes after inner join

Comment: What happen if you switch `group by` and `inner join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed basic SQL, but I would prefer to use `left outer join` for this.

```
select tip.descripcion, count(eq.idType) 
from TipoEquipo tip  
left outer join Equipos eq on tip.id=eq.idType 
group by tip.descripcion
```

Comment: Guess I was just burnt out yesterday, and couldn't even figure out a way. Thanks!!!

Comment: @HenryB Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This is basic sql, put join and group by in the right order and group by description not id.

```
select tip.descripcion, count(*) as count
from Equipos eq 
inner join TipoEquipo tip on tip.id=eq.idType 
group by tip.descripcion
```